# Xamarin Forms Custom Control binding issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a custom control that I supply a `List<string>` parameter and it draws a box for each string as a label.

Here is a version that is working.  Clicking 'Add Tab' adds one tab at a time for each click.

I want to change the code so the List is converted into a different type of object and that is what the control displays.

[image]

First I show the code that is working for the image above.  Then I show a changed version of the code that I am unable to get working.  Hopefully for anyone answering this question, seeing the before code that works and the after code that doesn't work, you can easily spot the issue.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App7"
             x:Class="App7.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <BoxView HeightRequest="100" />

        <local:CustomControl 
            SideTabs="{Binding MainNavigationTabs}" 
        />

        <Button Text="Add Tab" Command="{Binding AddTab}" />

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

**MainPageModel.cs**

```
public class MainPageModel : FreshBasePageModel
{
    public MainPageModel() { }

    public List<string> MainNavigationTabs { get; set; }

    private int _index = 0;

    public Command AddTab
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                _index++;

                var tabs = new List<string>();

                for (var index = 1; index <= _index; index++)
                {
                    tabs.Add($"Tab {index}");
                }

                MainNavigationTabs = tabs;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomControl.xaml**

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="App7.CustomControl"
                 BackgroundColor="Beige"
                 x:Name="this">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                             BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=SideTabs}">

                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentView WidthRequest="237"
                                         Margin="0"
                                         BackgroundColor="Blue"
                                         Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="White" />
                        </ContentView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**CustomControl.xaml.cs**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CustomControl : ContentView
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SideTabsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                       propertyName: "SideTabs",
                                       returnType: typeof(List<string>),
                                       declaringType: typeof(CustomControl),
                                       defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
                                       defaultValue: new List<string>());

    public List<string> SideTabs
    {
        get { return base.GetValue(SideTabsProperty) as List<string>; }
        set { base.SetValue(SideTabsProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I changed the CustomControl to transform the `List<string>` to a `List<SideTab>` object and have the control bind to that.  Here's the code...

**CustomControl.xaml.cs**

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CustomControl : ContentView
{
    public CustomControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty SideTabsProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                       propertyName: "SideTabs",
                                       returnType: typeof(List<string>),
                                       declaringType: typeof(CustomControl),
                                       defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
                                       defaultValue: new List<string>());

    public List<string> SideTabs
    {
        get
        {
            var tabs = new List<string>();

            foreach (var tab in _SideTabs)
            {
                tabs.Add(tab.Text);
            }

            return tabs;
        }
        set
        {
            var tabs = new List<SideTab>();

            foreach (var tab in value)
            {
                tabs.Add(new SideTab() { Text = tab });
            }

            _SideTabs = tabs;
        }
    }

    public List<SideTab> _SideTabs
    {
        get { return base.GetValue(SideTabsProperty) as List<SideTab>; }
        set { base.SetValue(SideTabsProperty, value); }
    }
}

public class SideTab
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

**CustomControl.xaml**

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="App7.CustomControl"
                    BackgroundColor="Beige"
                    x:Name="this">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                                BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=_SideTabs}">

                <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentView WidthRequest="237"
                                            Margin="0"
                                            BackgroundColor="Blue"
                                            Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" TextColor="White" />
                        </ContentView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Notice the addition of a property _SideTabs.  When SideTabs is set, it transforms the `List<string>` into a `List<SideTab>`.

How can I make this work?  Here is the result from the above code changes...

[image]

Comment: You haven't changed your SideTabsProperty to reflect the data type change in your last example. Also if you are just interested in different appearance based on a value on the model you are binding. TemplateSelector might be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this,

```
 public static readonly BindableProperty TabsListProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TabsList), typeof(List<TabItem>), typeof(ScrollableTabs), null, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
    {
        ((ScrollableTabs)bindable).InitializeTabs();
    });

    private void InitializeTabs()
    {
        //Write your logic here
    }


    public List<TabItem> TabsList
    {
        get
        {
            return (List<TabItem>)GetValue(TabsListProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TabsListProperty, value);

        }
    }
```

Comment: This led me to the solution. Thanks!

Comment: This also led me to a solution... thanks!